# django rest framework nested relationships -

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some trouble understanding Django Rest Framework. I am building an application, very simple. And for some reason I don't understand I am not able to make it work properly.

I am using:

- python: 3.4.0
- Django: 1.7.4
- Django Rest Framework: 3.0.5

Here is the thing:

```
#models.py
class Country(StandardMetadata, GeoBase):
    CONTINENT_CHOICES = (
        ('OC', 'Oceania'),
        ('EU', 'Europe'),
        ('AF', 'Africa'),
        ('NA', 'North America'),
        ('AN', 'Antarctica'),
        ('SA', 'South America'),
        ('AS', 'Asia'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CONTINENT_CHOICES, default='NA')
    iso2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    iso3 = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'


class Region(StandardMetadata, GeoBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    iso2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ', '.join([self.name, self.country.name])

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'country')
        verbose_name = 'Region/State/Province'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Regions/States/Provinces'


#serializers.py
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'slug', 'iso2', 'iso3', 'continent', 'lng', 'lat')


class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = CountrySerializer(read_only=True, required=True, many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'slug', 'iso2', 'lng', 'lat', 'country',)

#views.py
class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer


class RegionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Region.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegionSerializer

#urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'countries', CountryViewSet)
router.register(r'regions', RegionViewSet)
```

So for some reason I got this error when I try to access to this url ( http://192.168.33.30:5000/regions/ ): **May not set both `read_only` and `required`**

What am I missing ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

**EDIT**

I found one of my problem. I removed the line `unique_together = ('slug', 'country')` in my **Region** model. I set the **slug** field as unique. The second problem is that I had to break my model to make it work.

Comment: Isn't the solution already described in error message?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specify read-only in the Serializer, do this:

```
class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = CountrySerializer(required=True, many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'slug', 'iso2', 'lng', 'lat', 'country',)
        read_only_fields = ('country', )
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions but the problem remains.